# How to use pandas to create columns from one with pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pivot, pivot-table

I have a csv with unstructured information. I want to use pivot_table (or merge ?) from pandas to have only one rows for every instance.task_id.number and to spread out metric question in several colums.

For example if i have 4 instance.task_id_number, i need to have 4 columns of metric.question
I tried with pivot and pivot.table and merge but nothing match my expectation.

Thanks for your help !

#Edit : as asked, i did it as a example :

What i have :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", 2], ["A", 3], ["A", 6], ["B", 10], ["B", 11], ["B", 12]])
```

what i want :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["A", 2, 3, 6], ["B", 10, 11, 12]])
```

#Edit 2 : What i tried with pivot_table with the real dataframe. I put aggfunc with "metric.question and drop it in values.

I got the error :

AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'index'.

I tried to reset the index but it doesn't work better. The code :

```
import pandas as pd

stockage = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Import_Engie\asmt_assessment_instance_question.csv", encoding="cp1252")
df = pd.DataFrame(stockage)
#df = df.filter(["instance.task_id.number", "metric.question"], axis = 1)


df2 = df.reset_index(drop = True).pivot_table(index=['instance.task_id.number'],
             columns='metric.question',
             values=["instance","instance.trigger_id","instance.task_id.number","instance.taken_on","instance.state",
             "string_value","metric.order","value","sys_updated_on","instance.task_id.company",
             "instance.user.u_company_customer.u_customer_trigram","instance.task_id.contact_type",
             "instance.task_id.assignment_group"], aggfunc="metric.question")

print(df2)
df2.to_csv(r"C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Import_Engie\resultat.csv")
```

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame as a copyable piece of code for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: What is your expect output for `pivot`. You have `index='instance.task_id.number'` and `columns='metric.question'` but `values=?`

Comment: I edit the question as asked. As values i want the rows of metric.question. The csvfile is larger, i took only two columns to simplify the problem but after i have to add every columns, my first step is to have one "instance.task_id.number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
>>> df.assign(cols=df.groupby('instance.task_id.number').cumcount()) \
      .pivot(index='instance.task_id.number',
             columns='cols',
             values='metric.question') \
      .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)

             0   1   2   3
REQ0510079  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
REQ0527568  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
```

---

**Old answer**

Following my comment:

```
data = {'instance.task_id.number': ['REQ0510079','REQ0510079','REQ0510079','REQ0510079',
                                    'REQ0527568','REQ0527568','REQ0527568','REQ0527568'],
        'metric.question': ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Using `pivot`:

```
>>> df.pivot(index='instance.task_id.number',
             columns='metric.question',
             values='metric.question')

metric.question          Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
instance.task_id.number                
REQ0510079               Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
REQ0527568               Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
```

Comment: I got the error : "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Comment: It works for one column, thanks ! But then when i want to drop the filter i used and add every column on my csvfile it duplicate every columns the number of "instance.task_id.number". It does the job for every column i guess.

The filter i used is : 
df = df.filter(["instance.task_id.number", "metric.question"], axis = 1)

I still want only one instance.task_id.number, spread the metric question, but keep others values "normal"

Comment: You have to use `pivot_table` but you need to define an `aggfunc` to deal with duplicate values (first, last, mean, sum, ...). Try to setup an example with errors please.

Comment: I tried something, using tutoriel "Pivoting with aggregating" and pandas documentation

Comment: Aha yes, why ? I think there is no private information here

Comment: I don't know how to join the created chat